# SilverStripe page field do not work

Tags: php, html, silverstripe

I made a edit in my modules page field. All works without errors but when i go to page where i should see a hyper link it just show me

My ImageBlock.php 
class ImageBlock extends Block

```
{
    private static $db = array( 'WebsiteLinkHyper' => 'VarChar'); // THIS IS ADDED BY ME
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Images' => 'Image'

    );

    private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'Images' => array('SortOrder' => 'Int')
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $uploadField = null;
        if (class_exists('SortableUploadField')) {
            $uploadField = SortableUploadField::create('Images', _t('ImageBlock.IMAGES', 'Images'));
        } else {
            $uploadField = UploadField::create('Images', _t('ImageBlock.IMAGES', 'Images'));
        }

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $uploadField);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('WebsiteLinkHyper', 'Link'));// THIS IS ADDED BY ME
        $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

My imageBlock.ss

```
<% loop $Images.Sort('SortOrder') %>
<a href="$WebsiteLinkHyper"> //THIS IS ADDED
<figure>
    $Tag
    <figcaption>$Title</figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

all in admin panel works fine but when i go to page i see my content block but when i click view page source i see a empty href like this > `<a href="">`

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping the images and adding your `$WebsiteLinkHyper` inside that loop, so SilverStripe will be trying to access that property on your images rather than your block. Try bumping up the scope level:

```
<% loop $Images.Sort('SortOrder') %>
    <a href="{$Up.WebsiteLinkHyper}"> //THIS IS ADDED
    ...
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Now atleast i get something,  i get this <a href="."  Now there is just a dod not a link
And i cant put these in the code > {}

Comment: Yes you can put the curly braces there but they are used by the template processor to escape the sirverstripe variable.

Comment: So what should i do ?

Comment: I think you are using the SO as a wrong medium to figure out SilverStripe basics. First is suggest to whatch these https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ and at least start from here https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/common_variables/

Comment: Also be sure you are reading docs for the correct version of silverstripe

Comment: Also Robbie probably did a minor mistake on his answer $Up.$WebsiteLinkHyper should be $Up.WebsiteLinkHyper . Note unnecessary dollar sign

Comment: It wont work with $Up.WebsiteLinkHyper i still get empty href . Tryed this  already ;/

Comment: Maybe try `$Top.WebsiteLinkHyper`